# Python adds special characters to path-string

Tags: python, string, special-characters

I am trying to work with a path in Python 2.7

This is what I am trying to do in my main class:

```
program = MyProgram()
program.doSomething('C:\Eclipse\workspace\MyProgram\files\12345678_Testing1_ABCD005_Static_2214_File12.txt')
```

Inside the function `doSomething(filePath)` the string already looks like this:

[image: Deformated string]

So there is a kind of special character plus some characters are removed copletely. What could cause this problem?

Comment: Is that path correct? normally you need to escape back slashes or pass a raw string like this: `program.doSomething(r'C:\Eclipse\workspace\MyProgram\files\12345678_Testing1_ABCD005_Static_2214_File12.txt')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\` is escape char in Python. [According to docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), you have created string with `\f  ASCII Formfeed (FF)` character.

> String literals can be enclosed in matching single quotes (`'`) or
>   double quotes (`"`). They can also be enclosed in matching groups of
>   three single or double quotes (these are generally referred to as
>   triple-quoted strings). **The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape
>   characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline,
>   backslash itself, or the quote character.**

Either use double slashes (`\\` - to escape escape character) or use raw string literals (`r"some\path"`).

> String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R';
>   such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for
>   interpreting backslash escape sequences.

Comment: Or, more simply, use `/` as a path separator, which works fine on Windows, too.

Comment: The raw string literal worked like a charm for me! I was iterating through folders in windows10, and say a file such as `E:\Documents\Repo\img_download\img_CYzG4xdoXRq\1648001201_947978.jpg` was being instead read as `E:\Documents\Repo\img_download\img_CYzG4xdoXRqt8001201_947978.jpg`, which gave me an error of file not found.  `\164` was being interpreted as a `t` in the filename.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably overkill in your situation,
you could use `os.path.join` to build the path. With this you have two advantages:

- it builds paths using the current system's separator (Unix '/' VS Windows '\')
- you don't have to care about escaping the separator in case of windows

As said, this is probably overkill for your code:

```
import os.path
program = MyProgram()
my_path = os.path.join('C:', 
                       'Eclipse', 
                       'workspace', 
                       'MyProgram', 
                       'files',
                       '12345678_Testing1_ABCD005_Static_2214_File12.txt')
program.doSomething(my_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash seems to be creating a special character. Placing an extra backslash (to act as an escape charater) behind the backslashes should fix it.

```
program = MyProgram()
program.doSomething('C:\\Eclipse\\workspace\\MyProgram\\files\\12345678_Testing1_ABCD005_Static_2214_File12.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert Windows path names containing escape characters by converting it into raw string.

If you want to hard code your string then you can use

```
mypath = r'C:\this_is_my_path'
```

and python will ignore '\t' in the above string.

However if you have a string variable containing escape characters then you can use the below mentioned method.

```
def string2RawString(string):
    rawString = ''
    for i in string.split('\\'):
        rawString = rawString+("%r"%i).strip("'")+"\\"
    return rawString
```

Answer (score 0):

use r before your file path

```
program.doSomething(r'C:\Eclipse\workspace\MyProgram\files\12345678_Testing1_ABCD005_Static_2214_File12.txt')
```